# Converting Object to sequential array format - javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having following object structure

```
 var obj = {"0":"direct","1":"indirect","2":"dir","3":"indir"};
```

**Expected output is:**

```
result = [["direct","indirect"],["indirect","dir"],["dir","indir"]];
```

What I have tried:

```
    var result = [];
    var array = [];
    for(var key in obj){
          if(array.length <2) {
              array.push(obj[key]);
          }else{
              array =[];
              array.push(obj[key-1]);
           }

       if(array.length == 2){
            result.push(array);
       }
     }
   console.log(result);
```

I am getting the output as follows:

```
result = [["direct", "indirect"], ["indirect", "indir"]]
```

Comment: Why are you using an object as an array?

Comment: Actually i have to query like query = {filter:firstOne,filter:secondOne},{filter:secondOne,filter:thirdOne},{filter:thirdOne,filter:fourthOne}; in the mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're all strings that have at least one character, then you can do this:

```
var obj = {"0":"direct","1":"indirect","2":"dir","3":"indir"};
var result = [];

for (var i = 1; obj[i]; i++) {
    result.push([obj[i-1], obj[i]]);
}
```

It starts at index `1` and pushes the current and previous items in an Array. It continues as long as the values are truthy, so if there's an empty string, it'll stop.

If there could be falsey values that need to be included, then you should count the properties first.

```
var obj = {"0":"direct","1":"indirect","2":"dir","3":"indir"};
var result = [];

var len = Object.keys(obj).length;

for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    result.push([obj[i-1], obj[i]]);
}
```